# How do I tell if a program is printing to stderr or stdout in the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell-script

**NOTE:** a newline appears but od -c doesn't display it.

My music player's status command (`quodlibet --status | od -c`) has three states, and I'm trying to write a conditional based on that output. The outputs from that command are like this (may differ depending on the configuration).

1. I think this is printing to stderr because `od -c` doesn't display properly, even though it does for the other commands.

   ```
   not-running
   0000000
   ```
2. paused

   ```
   0000000   p   a   u   s   e   d       P   a   n   e   d   B   r   o   w
   0000020   s   e   r       1   .   0   0   0       s   h   u   f   f   l
   0000040   e       o   n       0   .   2   2   8  \n
   0000053
   ```
3. playing

   ```
   0000000   p   l   a   y   i   n   g       P   a   n   e   d   B   r   o
   0000020   w   s   e   r       1   .   0   0   0       s   h   u   f   f
   0000040   l   e       o   n       0   .   2   3   2  \n
   0000054
   ```

My goal is to remove everything except "not-running", "paused", or "playing" and use that in a conditional, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

status=$(quodlibet --status | awk '{split($0,m," "); printf "%s",m[1]}' | tr -d '\000\007\010\n')
if [ "$status" = "playing" ]; then
  quodlibet --print-playing '<artist>: <title>' | cut -c1-45
else
  echo -n "$status"
fi
```

In the case where the player isn't running though this always prints a newline in the terminal after "not-running." Even if I do something like this

```
echo -n "$(quodlibet --print-playing '<artist>: <title>' | cut -c1-45)"
```

If I pipe that output to `od -c`, I get the same

```
not-running
0000000
```

which isn't right. The newline doesn't show up, but its their in the terminal.

#### Questions

- What's causing this?
- Is the command printing to standard error when the program isn't running?
- How can I determine this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of ways to approach this.

1. merge streams

   You could by pass determining the difference all together and simply merge STDERR and STDOUT.

   #### Example

   ```
   quodlibet --status 2>&1 | ...
   ```
2. use grep

   You could chop the output down by using the `-o` & `-E` switches to `grep`.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ echo "...blah not-running blah..." | grep -Eo "not-running|paused|playing"
   not-running

   $ echo "...blah paused blah..." | grep -Eo "not-running|paused|playing"
   paused

   $ echo "...blah playing blah..." | grep -Eo "not-running|paused|playing"
   playing
   ```

   This will cut everything out except for the strings that match the regex argument to `grep`.
3. determine the stream's type

   You can use the `-t` switch to determine the type of the file descriptor stream.

   *excerpt from Bash man page*

   > -t fd True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.
   >
   > where fd is one of:
   >
   > 0:     stdin
   >   1:     stdout
   >   2:     stderr

   #### Example

   This detects if the output is coming from STDOUT.

   ```
   $ if [ -t 1 ]; then echo "from STDOUT"; fi
   from STDOUT
   ```

   Returns "from STDOUT" since the output is coming through while:

   ```
   $ (if [ -t 1 ]; then echo "from STDOUT"; fi) | cat
   ```

   Returns nothing, since the output is being directed to `cat`.

Comment: merging the streams did it. I thought it was something like that but I couldnt quite gte the syntax right.